# Getting to Buffalo Depew Amtrak in the evening

Tags: public-transport, amtrak, night-transport, buffalo

I would like to catch the westbound [Lake Shore Limited](http://www.amtrak.com/ccurl/559/873/Lake-Shore-Limited-Schedule-011314.pdf) that departs Buffalo-Depew station at 23:59 (11:59 PM).

Is there any public transit from downtown Buffalo around this time (specifically, from the [Buffalo Metropolitan Transportation Center](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffalo_Metropolitan_Transportation_Center))
(I arrive by Greyhound bus at 22:30 / 10:30 PM)?

[Niagara Frontier Transportation Authority](http://metro.nfta.com/) services Buffalo-Depew Amtrak on line 46, [but this does not appear to run in the evening](http://metro.nfta.com/Routes/pdfs/46.pdf).  Is there any other alternative, or is a taxi the only way?  Perhaps an airport shuttle would be running and could stop there?

Answer (score 3):

Taxi would likely be your only alternative, while some buses around downtown Buffalo run into early morning hours the bus you will need to get to the [Depew Station](https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=42.883333,-78.871944+%2842.883333,+-78.871944%29&daddr=Buffalo+Depew+Station,+Depew,+NY&hl=en&ll=42.908364,-78.730216&spn=0.012259,0.017402&sll=42.899358,-78.800125&sspn=0.196171,0.278435&geocode=FQVZjgIdeIJM-w%3BFYm1jgIdSLpO-yFG000kAig72yljLAaZagvTiTFG000kAig72w&oq=depew+station&dirflg=r&ttype=now&noexp=0&noal=0&sort=def&mra=prev&t=m&z=16&start=0) [stops running at about 7:30pm](http://metro.nfta.com/Routes/pdfs/46.pdf) the express bus which also stops at the station only has [1 run during the day](http://metro.nfta.com/Routes/pdfs/68.pdf).